# How can I count odd digits in java, but if that number has more then one odd digit count the first one only

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a program that implements an array of numbers and if that array has an odd digit in it add it to the sum. For example 123(has 1 and 3 as odd digits) 222(no odd digits) and 434(has 3 as a odd digit). The end sum should be 123+434. This is what I came up with but the sum would be 123+123+434(Sice 123 has 2 odd numbers it counts it two times)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.print("Number of numbers: ");
        int j = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("List of numbers: ");
        int arr[] = new int[j];
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            int num = arr[i];

               while (num > 0) {

                  System.out.println(num % 10);
                  if (num%2!=0)
                  {
                     sum= sum+arr[i];
                     System.out.println("SUM IS: "+sum);
                  }
                  
                  num = num / 10;

               }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add the same number multiple times, just `break` out of the `while` loop as soon as you add it the first time.

```
while (num > 0) {

    System.out.println(num % 10);
    if (num%2!=0)
    {
        sum = sum+arr[i];
        System.out.println("SUM IS: "+sum);
        break; // add this line
    }

    num = num / 10;

}
```

The `break` statement **immediately ends the loop** it is inside of (regardless if it is a `for`, `while` or a `do ... while` loop).

There is also a `continue` statement (which you don't need here), that **immediately continues to the next loop iteration**, skipping the execution of any code after the `continue` statement that is part of the loop.